# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP Issue in Android

Tags: android

I have many activities like, login->main->a,b,c,d->logout [a,b,c,d are four activities]. when I login app then it goes to main and finish login activity. and main launches each activity separately. But when I am in a/b/c/d(any of one) activity and press logout it has go to login activity through `startActivity()` and clear all previous activities. But It cannot work when I pressed back it goes to a/b/c/d[one which start last]. I have use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, but it cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK should do the trick. Mind that you need to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with this flag.

Comment: Yes, use this. Remember that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is API11+ AFAIK, but you can use the compatibility package to use this flag in API4+. See `IntentCompat` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html